# Facebook post Exception: (#100) link URL is not properly formatted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im getting this error when I try to post on my wall via my FBApp. On local host all works good. Here my code example.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
 'appId'  => API_KEY,
 'secret' => API_SECRET,
 'cookie' => true,
));

$args = array(
      'message' => $_SESSION['fields']['message'],
      'name' => 'Look at POSTCARD',
      'caption' => $context['ProjectName'],
      'link' => $data['view_url']."&s=".$hash,
      'description' => 'We are a lifestyle community with hotel services in the heart of San Francisco,check us out and ask a question.',
      'picture' => $body_all["thumb"],
      'actions' => array(array('name' => 'SEND A POSTCARD',
                        'link' => FACEBOOK_ACTION_URL."?next_postcard_id=".$postcard_id))
      );
```

at this string, exception `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) link URL is not properly formatted` is throwing

`$post_fb_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed/", "post", $args);`

Comment: http://apps.facebook.com/268304686540809/?view=b64baf1fe00a8927335fe417c2cbee11&s=b64baf1fe00a8927335fe417c2cbee11

Comment: i don`t know why, now all works good, but there is another exception - `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` any body know, how solve it?

Comment: login to Facebook before make an api call

Comment: my api call, cant be before login, because only after login, or login status check he can see wall post interface. And i try to dump $me befor api call, and this variable was exist.

Comment: before login i do FB.init only

Comment: FB.init - is a clientside javascript, when code in the original post is a serverside php.

Answer (score -1):

Anton Sementsov
I am not good at PHP side, but good in Java! faced same problem Code-100

Using APP_ACCESS_TOKEN and hitting URL 

 **https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&message=JustTest&link=http//domain/path/file.jsp**

Using ApacheHTTP client to hit the URL, Problem is that If parameter is passed to **[link]** is encoded before hitting the URL you will get Error Code:100

If URL is encoded before HIT, You have to ensure that value of parameter **link** is not get encoded and passed in same UTF format.